# Rails 4 belong/has_many relation - delete associated attribute but Keep the associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 2 models as follows: Deal and Prize.

Deal,

```
belongs_to :prize,          :foreign_key => 'prize_id'
```

Prize,

```
has_many   :deals,  dependent: :destroy
```

My problem is simple:

If I delete a Prize, I want to keep the Deals which would be associated but *remove* the prize_id value inside the Deals objects that were associated with this prize_id that was just deleted.

- Today, when using dependent:destroy, it deletes the whole line, i.e., the whole record associated.
- I tried removing the 'dependent: :destroy', but then when I delete a Prize, it does delete the prize but it lets inside Deal's prized_id column the id number of the deleted Prize, which is a problem.

How can I delete a Prize and then have the associated records (the Deal objects associated) remain/keep existing and only change inside the Deal's table the prize_id (from the prize_id in question to nil)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove your `dependent: :destroy`
2. Create and `after_destroy` callback that sets all `prize_id` fields in all associated `deals` to nil.

   `after_destroy do
       self.deals.update_all(prize_id: nil)
   end`

---

**Note:**
Starting Rails 5, any model with `belongs_to` association will not allowed to have a `nil`  foreign key.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `dependent: nullify`